# Execute mysql commands in linux terminal using Python

Tags: python, mysql, linux, terminal, command

I would like to automate the setup of a database and I would like to do it by using a python script to execute some commands in a linux terminal.

But I cannot see any way of executing commands in the terminal after connection to mysql database.

Below you can see a part of the script:

```
from time import sleep
from os import system

print("Setting up the database...\n")
system("sudo mysql -u root")
sleep(2)
```

This starts mysql, and after this none of the commands I try to execute from python get executed.

For example, I would like to run commands like these:

```
system("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;")
system("CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';")
system("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'user'@'localhost';")
```

Is this possible?

Edit 1: Potential solution as suggested by @AndHeFallen:

In python I create an sql file named db.sql, then run this in the terminal:

```
with open("db.sql","w") as db:
    db.write("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;\n")
    db.write("CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';\n")
    db.write("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'user'@'localhost';\n")

system("sudo mysql -u root < db.sql")
```

Comment: Why not connect to mysql directly from python and issue statements through that connectiin?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. How would I do that.

Comment: There's no correct answer b/c this is not how you work with any database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that. If you want to interact with your MySQL database with a Python script, you'll need to connect directly to your db with an api like [MySQLdb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html). (I may be wrong but the way you want to do may cause security issues)

Comment: I don't want to connect to an existing DB, I want to create a new DB, and create users.

Comment: You could maybe generate a .sql file then ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

I have something similar for automating the update process for an specific application.

basically, using `subprocess.check_call` is all you need.

It would handle any exception or error output and stop/continue the execution as you need.

I'm even capable of using `pv` for monitoring the mysql data transfer

```bash
# this is the command I need to run
$ pv /resources/sql/script_sample.sql | mysql  --defaults-file=/resources/config/config-local-dev.cnf --protocol=tcp --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --database=my_sample_db
```

```py
# my python script
run(
    command="pv /resources/sql/script_sample.sql | mysql  --defaults-file=/resources/config/config-local-dev.cnf --protocol=tcp --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --database=my_sample_db",
)
# or
run(
    command='mysql  --defaults-file=/resources/config/config-local-dev.cnf --protocol=tcp --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --execute="CREATE DATABASE IF EXISTS sample_db" ',
)
```

source:

```py
import subprocess

class ShellColors:
    """Shell Colors"""
    HEADER = "\033[95m"
    OKBLUE = "\033[94m"
    OKCYAN = "\033[96m"
    OKGREEN = "\033[92m"
    WARNING = "\033[93m"
    FAIL = "\033[91m"
    ENDC = "\033[0m"
    BOLD = "\033[1m"
    UNDERLINE = "\033[4m"

def run(command=""):
    """run command"""
    try:
        terminal_color = (ShellColors.WARNING, "")[allow_execution]
       
        subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
         
        print(f"{terminal_color}{command}{ShellColors.ENDC}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        print(f"{ShellColors.FAIL}ERROR: {error}{ShellColors.ENDC}")
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError from error ## I added this line because I need to print the error above, and then stop execution
```

[video example](https://capture.dropbox.com/C5rLi49BbCBzGrMs)